# Travis could not find bundler 1.7.4

Tags: travis-ci

Build job fails after updating bundler version in gemspec: https://travis-ci.org/yandex-money/yandex-money-sdk-ruby/jobs/38536867

How I can update bundler to 1.7.4 version?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to add the following code in an additional `install` section of your .travis file:

```
  gem uninstall bundler
  gem install bundler --version '1.7.4'
```

So, the beginning of your .travis file will be:

```
language: ruby
install:
  - gem uninstall bundler
  - gem install bundler --version '1.7.4'
script: "rake"
```

Comment: Almost :) I'm need to change install section to this: `rvm @global do gem uninstall bundler -x && gem install bundler -v '~> 1.7.4' && bundle install` and all works now. But it seems to be very hacky... but works :)

Comment: Better to put the gem uninstall/install in a before_install section (per Danil's answer), otherwise you need to invoke "bundle install" in the install section too.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your **.travis.yml**:

```
before_install: gem install bundler --pre
```